# Cannot Serialize SQL Connection using WCF

Tags: sql, wcf, serialization, wsdl, sqlconnection

I am aware that you cannot, nor does it make sense to serialize a SQL Connection.  However I have an issue where identical code prevails on both our production and development servers and our production web service works fine, while our development machine fails (along with my local dev machine).

The error I get is this:

> An ExceptionDetail, likely created by
>   IncludeExceptionDetailInFaults=true, whose value is:
>   System.InvalidOperationException: An exception was thrown in a call to
>   a WSDL export extension:
>   System.ServiceModel.Description.DataContractSerializerOperationBehavior
>   contract: http://tempuri.org/:IWFHandlerService ---->
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.InvalidDataContractException: Type
>   'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCredential' cannot be serialized. Consider
>   marking it with the DataContractAttribute attribute, and marking all
>   of its members you want serialized with the DataMemberAttribute
>   attribute.  If the type is a collection, consider marking it with the
>   CollectionDataContractAttribute.  See the Microsoft .NET Framework
>   documentation for other supported types.    at
>   System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContract.DataContractCriticalHelper.ThrowInvalidDataContractException(String
>   message, Type type)...

The source code I have has the following method in it:

```
Public Function GetCentralConnection() As SqlClient.SqlConnection Implements IWFHandlerService.GetCentralConnection

    Dim conn As New SqlClient.SqlConnection(My.Settings.MDISCentralConnection)
    Return conn

End Function
```

When I review the WSDL from the production web service, I can clearly see the GetCentralConnection method being available to me.

If we can start a dialog to begin looking to what the solution might be, but I'm at my last nerve with why this service will not run on a different web server.